# Make arbitrary value accessible through @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 3.2.9 and developing a web application.

The application fetches some configurations from external resources ( like database or public URLs etc. ) on startup in a `ServletContextListener` and I want to make those configurations available for injection through `@Value` annotation.

Unfortunately, it seems that `@Value` can only be used to inject values from `properties` files or system properties.

Please anyone tell me is it possible? If so, how to achieve this?

Comment: You can only inject values known by the Spring context. So to achieve your goals you need to make the Spring context aware of your configuration values from ServletContextListener.

Comment: http://www.opencodez.com/java/how-to-load-application-properties-from-database.htm